# C#' MVVM Observable Proxies aka Android LiveData?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, android-livedata

I am developing a C# wpf mvvm application in which the Model Data is represented by hierarchies and my ViewModels have to observe Parts of the hierachies in between. I would like to come up with a design that makes the application easier to maintain when the structural hierarchies of the Model change.

Example:

The Model has a hierarchy A->B->C->D. The ViewModel wants to get change notifications of D and B. At some point another ViewModel sets A to a completly new value and all other observing ViewModels have to be notified that their respetive D and B are no longer valid.

My design idea so far:
I flatten the hierachy of the models by replacing the direct reference with an unique Identifier like GUID. When a ViewModels wants to get an instance of D it actually has to ask a Repository to get an observable Proxy of D. When a write to A occurs, the observable Proxy gets notified about it and therefore the ViewModel also gets notified. The life cycle of the obervable proxy is bound to the ViewModel thats using it, e.g. the ViewModel decides when the observable proxy will be disposed.

Is there maybe already a pattern that solves this problem in C# MVVM? I saw that Android Jetpack introduced LiveData and it looks very similar to what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Anemic Domain Model, entities that reference other entities with unique keys and messagebus is the way to go.

After studying the problem I came up with a few proven solutions.

According to DDD (Domain Driven Design): Its OK to reference other aggregates by Index but not object reference. Aggregates should only be accessed via the aggregate root and encapsulate logic and child entities inside the aggregate root. This is OOP and you end up with easy to use objects that overtime become fat filled with methods and fields because, well just look at the WPF framework UserControl when you enter 'this.' and an accordeon of fields, methods and events reveals to you. One could argue that you can use inheritance and move methods out with mediators to reduce your 5kloc OOP source files, but mediator is just procedural style programming in disguise which leads me to...

The Anemic Domain Model. Entities are just data containers without behavior (methods) and only have fields that are simple or reference other entities by keys. On top of the dumb entities are the 'services' which are just stateless collections of methods that run on the dumb entities. Every write operation by a service will trigger some kind of messaging, either a message bus or other.

The anemic domain model pattern is very popular in games industry right now, but they call it 'Data oriented Design' or DOD. DOD boils down to lots of dumb data component objects where some methods run on them with the goal to achieve easy parallelism and cache coherence. In my opinion thats just old school procedural C programming with handles and it makes sense for high performance applications.